# When do we use allowMissingFiles for deploy target?

Tags: apex, ant, migration-tool

Could somebody please explain me the real time situation where we would need to set the attribute `allowMissingFile="true"` for deploy target for Force Migration tool.

I read the documentation about the same [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.daas.meta/daas/forcemigrationtool_deploy.htm) but I am still not sure about when we would need it. Any example would be great.

Sorry for posting a simple question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this in  deployments from sandbox to sandbox saving some time.

When set to true deployment succeed without any warnings even if there are some missing file inspite of being specified in the package.xml

package.xml is not strictly checked for matching files in zip folder As suggested never use for PROD but during repetitive quick deployment to sandbox it will save some time needed to work the package.xml .Instead just remove files not needed for deployment